# How to change getLegendGraphic option default?

Tags: geoserver, getlegendgraphic

I have several geoserver layers that have only one rule.  By default, they do not get a text label in the legend.  I know if you use LEGEND_OPTIONS=forceLabels:on in the getLegendGraphic call, it will label it.  Is there any way to make that the default for my geoserver installation?

Answer (score 1):

No, to the extent of my knowledge there is none, besides changing the code, as of GeoServer 2.10.x (current stable).

If you are interested in getting that functionality see a guide here:
https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer